# Django pymongo update_many ''Cannot use the part (y) of (x.y) to traverse the element ({x: []})'}'

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection like this with sample documents as:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "64b28bafb2ea43dd940b920d"
    },
    "title": "Village Libraries",
    "keywords": {
      "bn": [
        {
          "$ref": "mcoll_keywords",
          "$id": {
            "$oid": "64b28badb2ea43dd940b920b"
          }
        }
      ],
      "en": [
        {
          "$ref": "mcoll_keywords",
          "$id": {
            "$oid": "64b28aacb2ea43dd940b920a"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "64b676b3b2ea43dd940b9230"
    },
    "title": "Folk Tales",
    "keywords": {
      "bn": [
        {
          "$ref": "mcoll_keywords",
          "$id": {
            "$oid": "64b67683b2ea43dd940b922d"
          }
        }
      ],
      "en": [
        {
          "$ref": "mcoll_keywords",
          "$id": {
            "$oid": "64b676afb2ea43dd940b922e"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I would like to run a multi update query on this collection (using Python (Django and pymongo)) like:

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  "$pull": {
    "keywords.bn": {
      "$id": ObjectId("64b67683b2ea43dd940b922d")
    }
  }
},
{
  "multi": true
})
```

But running the update query:

```python
...
from pymongo import MongoClient
...

print('q= '+str({'$pull': {'keywords.bn': {'$id': meta_bid}}}))
# OUTPUT: q= {'$pull': {'keywords.bn': {'$id': ObjectId('64b67683b2ea43dd940b922d')}}}
y= ent_col.update_many({}, {'$pull': {'keywords.bn': {'$id' : meta_bid}}})
```

results in the following error:

> full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 28, 'errmsg': 'Cannot use the part
> (bn) of (keywords.bn) to traverse the element ({keywords: []})'}

I have tested the query in Mongo Playground ([link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g5B7T9TtPY6)) and it works fine there. So what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for reading this so far and also thanks for giving a thought.

Comment: Is it possible there is a version mismatch. What version of MongoDB do you use?

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/NX3qNnoguxH recreated issue when `keywords:[]` as the error says. looks like u have doc like that. so maybe `{ "keywords": { "$ne": [] } }` as the first param of update to ignore those?

Comment: MongoDB 5.0.6 Enterprise

Comment: Yeah @cmgchess, it is the problem. You nailed it!

Comment: @sariDon cool u can answer if u want how u solved it

Comment: Sure. Let me complete the implementation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The credit for this answer totally goes to @cmgchess 's comment to the question. Changing the query to:

```
y= ent_col.update_many({'keywords': {'$ne': []}}, {'$pull': {'keywords.bn': {'$id' : meta_bid}}}, upsert=False)
```

did the job.

The problem was in some documents the value of the 'keywords' were `[]`.

As an alternative, the 'keywords' with values `[]` can be updated to `{'bn': [], 'en': []}` and the document insertion/updation code to be updated likewise (not to set the 'keywords' as `[]`). Sample update code is as follows:

```
x= ent_col.update_many({'keywords': []}, {'$set': {'keywords': {'bn': [], 'en': []}}, upsert=False)
```

In this case, the query in the question will work without modification.